# D3.js d3.json returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am do not know much about javascript or JSON and I am not sure why this is not working.

A level of my JSON is below, but it basically is

```
[{'Africa' : {'children':[{stuff}], 'name':Africa} ...other continents
```

The pattern is always the same, where the a dict key is defined, in it is children and its name.

When I load it into d3.json, I get the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

```
d3.json("data/output.json", function(error, json) {
  root = json[0];
  update(root);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a problem with my my json or do I need to add more detail in the d3.json function?

I generated my json in python like this

```
def build_tree(d, val):
    return [{id_:{'name': name, 'children': build_tree(d, id_)} for id_, name in d[val]}]
```

My JSON is this

```
 [{'Africa': {'children': [{'Egypt': {'children': [{'EG-Cables': {'children': [{'H03VVH2F2x0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                    'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                        'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                   'H05RRF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                     'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                   'H05VVF2x1.00mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                 'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                      'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                   'H05VVF3G0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                  'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                      'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                   'H05VVF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                     'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                   'H05VVF3G1.5mm': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                     'name': 'Cables'}}],
                                                                     'name': 'Products'},
                                                       'EG-Plug': {'children': [{'BS1363': {'children': [{'13A/V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                    'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                            'name': 'Plug'},
                                                                                 'CEE-7/XVLL': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                           'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                'name': 'Plug'},
                                                                                 'CEE-XVLL': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                         'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                              'name': 'Plug'},
                                                                                 'EN-50075-XVL': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                              'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                  'name': 'Plug'}}],
                                                                   'name': 'Products'}}],
                                         'name': 'Country'},
                               'Nigeria': {'children': [{'NG-Cables': {'children': [{'H03VVH2F2x0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                      'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                          'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                     'H05RRF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                  'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                       'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                     'H05VVF2x1.00mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                   'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                        'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                     'H05VVF3G0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                    'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                        'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                     'H05VVF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                  'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                       'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                     'H05VVF3G1.5mm': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                  'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                       'name': 'Cables'}}],
                                                                       'name': 'Products'},
                                                         'NG-Plug': {'children': [{'BS1363': {'children': [{'13A/V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                      'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                              'name': 'Plug'},
                                                                                   'SABS-164/1:1992': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                  'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                       'name': 'Plug'}}],
                                                                     'name': 'Products'}}],
                                           'name': 'Country'},
                               'South-Africa': {'children': [{'ZA-Cables': {'children': [{'H03VVH2F2x0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                           'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                               'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                          'H05RRF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                       'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                            'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                          'H05VVF2x1.00mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                        'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                             'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                          'H05VVF3G0.75mm': {'children': [{'2.5A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                         'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                             'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                          'H05VVF3G1.0mm': {'children': [{'10A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                       'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                            'name': 'Cables'},
                                                                                          'H05VVF3G1.5mm': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                       'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                            'name': 'Cables'}}],
                                                                            'name': 'Products'},
                                                              'ZA-Plug': {'children': [{'SABS-164/1:1992': {'children': [{'16A/250V': {'children': [{}],
                                                                                                                                       'name': 'Max-Rating'}}],
                                                                                                            'name': 'Plug'}}],
                                                                          'name': 'Products'}}],
                                                'name': 'Country'}}],
                 'name': 'Africa'},
```

Comment: Check the `error` argument for an error message

Comment: The error message means that `json` has no value: You are trying to access the `0` property of the value `undefined`, which doesn't exist. As joews suggests, you should check `error` for a reason why `json` has no value.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(anonymous function) @ (index):48event @ d3.js:491respond @ d3.js:1904

Comment: I also note that the JSON you have posted is not fully formed - it has unclosed brackets at the end. Consider using a tool such as JSONLint: http://jsonlint.com/ to ensure that you are supplying valid JSON.

Comment: @lost I suspect you have posted the error message that appears in your javascript console rather than the value of the `error` variable in your callback function.

Comment: that is correct.  Jsonlint returned an error in the json script, that must be it

Comment: Parse error on line 2:
[    {        'Africa': {        
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Comment: How do I get the call back function?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I have to figure this out myself. I posted the question too quickly without working it through, This is day 4 on this thing

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. The root cause of your issue is a problem with the JSON you are passing to d3.js: it is incorrectly formed. I suggest using JSONLint to verify that `data/output.json` is in a correct format: http://jsonlint.com/.

In addition, you should check for parsing errors in the callback function when you read in the data. For instance, try writing something like this:

```
d3.json("data/output.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(error); // I would suggest a more sophisticated UI that just 
                      // an alert box, but this suffices as an example.
    }
    else {
        root = json[0];
        update(root);
    }
});
```